# Connect to raspberry pi from a web server

Tags: python, linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry pi on my home network. This is set up on my router, so it has a 192.168.x.x IP address. I have a python server running on my pi that is listening for incoming connections on a fixed port (48000).

I would like to connect to this raspberry pi from a machine that is on my work network (IP address 10.x.x.x.) My work PC can connect to the internet, but when I am on my work PC I don't know the external IP address of my home router.

Any ideas on how I can do this without having to set up a static IP address and port forwarding on my home router?

I'm not en expert, but I have some python code that can connect to the Pi when I am on same local network as the pi, but it doesn't work when I am on a network that is not the same as which my raspberry pi is on.

Any ideas on what approach I can take?

I initially thought about setting up a service on the pi that will post it's local IP address by email if the IP address changes, but this is useless since the local IP address is not routable.

Comment: Does your home router have a white external IP?

Comment: `without having to set up a static IP address and port forwarding on my home router` just curious - why can't you port forward?

Comment: Does your home IP really change that often?  Have your router port forward 48000 to your PI.

Comment: I sometimes use a LTE mobile hotspot for internet access at home. This can't do port forwarding (service provider blocks it)

Comment: @Duck: My IP changes often, since I use a mobile hotspot for internet access.

Comment: @AndreySobolev: when my router/mobile hotspot is up, it does have an external/routable IP.

Answer (score 2):

You should register with a free DNS service, such as no-ip (https://www.noip.com/managed-dns) and configure dynamic dns with your router (given it is able to do so). Then your router is always available at a given hostname. A potential domain for you could be e.g. user3308997.no-ip.org

Port forwarding or NAT must be setup in your router so, that e.g. the url http://user3308997.no-ip.org:8001 could be forwarded to your PI server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to muck around with your router - but you will need some kind of single stable 'meeting point' for the two.

An amazon EC2 micro instance would work fine.

You can then use that to tie the two together with SSH port forwarding (tunnelling).

Here are some examples:

http://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/#.Uv20jXj9_UI

Answer (score 0):

If you have another computer (it doesn't matter how old or slow, it'll work either way (and I bet you do)), you can [download VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/), plug in your Ethernet cable to your Raspberry Pi, then [find your Raspberry Pi's IP address](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ip-address.md), and use VNC Viewer to control your Raspberry Pi from that other computer.

And no, with this you don't need a "static IP" and all that hard stuff.

I hope I help with this :)